# mongoose aggregation not returning expected result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently learning aggregation and some related methods, after following mongoose and mongodb docs i tried it. but i am having problem.

```
Follow.aggregate([
            { $match: { user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) } },
            { $unwind: '$followers' },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'accounts',
                    localField: 'followers',
                    foreignField: '_id',
                    as: 'followers'
                }
            },
          { $project: { name: 1, photo: 1 } },

        ]).exec((err, followers) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(followers);
            res.send(followers);
        });
```

I want to get the followers of that userID and select the followers names and photo, but i am only getting the objectid of the matched document

```
[ { _id: 5bfe2c529419a560fb3e92eb } ]
```

expected output

```
 [ { _id: 5bfe2c529419a560fb3e92eb , name: 'john doe", photo: 'cat.jpg'} ]
```

Follow Model

```
const FollowSchema = new Schema({
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account',
        required: true,
    },
    following: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account',
        required: true,
    }],
    followers: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account',
        required: true,
    }],
});
```

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: Removing second `$unwind` stage will resolve.

Comment: Anthomy, removing unwind gives me same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `$project` stage is wrong you would get that result. Try removing it first and see the output. To me it seems you should have something like this there:

```
{ $project: { "followers.name": 1, "followers.photo": 1 } },
```

Comment: You are right... eslint forced me write the $project differently